# Is there a way to get an information who started a collision?

Tags: unreal-engine4

I have two actors in my project, sometimes AI Pawn is causing a collision and sometimes a Player is causing it. Is there a way to distinguish it?

Comment: What do you mean by started it? If you're after who's moving faster then that's be something like `if( playerPawn->GetVelocity().SizeSquared() > aiPawn->GetVelocity().SizeSquared()) { /* player is moving faster */ }`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the onHit function for the AI Pawn and Player?

Answer (score 0):

Both in C++ and Blueprint, collision events give you a `FHitResult` (displayed as just HitResult in BP). Here is [reference](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Engine/FHitResult/).

This result contains both the Actor and Component that was hit/overlapped/traced.

So, the object calling the collision event is first object, and `YourFHitResult.Actor` is the other object.

In BP, you can use the `break hit result` node to get the actor/component.